# Trying to run simple hello world node script and get module.js:340 throw err;

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, module

Im on ubuntu and have node version v0.10.25. Im trying to run a simple script called test.js by using

```
node test.js
```

on the terminal. The code in the file is:

```
console.log("hello world");
```

I get the following errorr:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/home/aymen/Desktop/Tests/test.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

Comment: You need to run `node test.js` in the folder where the test.js is located. If you are still receiving this error message when running node in the correct folder try checking if the current user has permissions to read the file

Comment: I'm in the same directory and iv also tried providing the full path. I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not in the same directory. Try to provide the full path of the test.js. node /home/user/directory/test.js, Or just run the node in the same directory as test.js

Comment: I'm in the same directory and iv also tried providing the full path. I still get the same error.

Comment: [root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# pwd
/root
[root@localhost ~]# vim test.js
[root@localhost ~]# node test.js
hello world
[root@localhost ~]# cat test.js
console.log("hello world");
[root@localhost ~]#